# bind or print from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am accessing my selected file using a directive as suggested by some SO answers,and i am able to console my file name in the directive.Now i want to bind that name to html from that directive.....how can i do that??

See the p tag after input

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="file" myfilename />
  <P>{{files[0].name}}</p>
  </body>
<script>
  
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myfilename', [function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function  (evt) {
               scope.files = evt.target.files;
                console.log(scope.files[0].name);
                
            });
        }
    };
}]);
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add scope.$apply() after scope.files = evt.target.files; in direcives.

The reason why it does not show the updated value immediately is because the 2 way binding updates the parent (or the consumer scope of the directive) scope's bound value only during the digest cycle. Digest cycle happens after the ng-click is triggered. And hence $scope.files in the controller is not yet updated. You can get around this in many ways by using a timeout which will defer the action to run at the end of the digest cycle. You could also do it by setting an object which holds the value as 2-way bound property. Since 2-way bound property and parent scope share the same object reference you will see the change immediately.

Here is the full code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <input type="file" myfilename />
  <P>{{files[0].name}}</p>
  </body>
<script>

  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

});
app.directive('myfilename', [function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('change', function  (evt) {
               scope.files = evt.target.files;
               scope.$apply();
                console.log(scope.files[0].name);

            });
        }
    };
}]);
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and you mentioned like  "You could also do it by setting an object which holds the value as 2-way bound property. Since 2-way bound property and parent scope share the same object reference you will see the change immediately".....as  i am a poor student with theory.... can u show the practical code of this